# I cannot open my menu when i scroll to the tables

Tags: html, css, header, position

Is there a way to move static positioned header? (like top:50px; in css)
I need to move my static header from top for like 50px; Is there a way?
P.S: I need to have static positioning, I cannot change that.

Comment: set your code here or in jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use top padding to add space between the header and the element above it. For example:

```
.header {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for lol I totally forgot about margin. Thank you!